# Problema com Bloqueio de data datatable editor

Tags: javascript, datatable

```
{
        label: "Data Nascimento:",
        name: "Cliente.DataNasc",
        type:   "datetime",
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        def:    function () { return new Date(); },
        attr:   { autocomplete: "off" }
    },
```

Preciso colocar um range de 100 anos contando com hoje para trás, ex: pessoas com mais de 100 anos não podem cadastrar. E preciso bloquear uma data em especifico 01/01/1900

Comment: Você precisa fornecer mais detalhes de seu problema. Qual o problema em si, qual instrução em que ele ocorre, etc. Detalhe-o para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Não resposta sua própria pergunta. Coloque a atualização na própria questão para manter a organização. Além de mostrar o json com as informações, adicione o trecho HTML onde está sera inserida.

Comment: Já corrigi, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Ao construir um objeto com new Date(), você pode informar 3 parâmetros: ano, mês (começando com 0) e dia).

Talvez, no seu caso, você possa usar algo assim:

```
const hoje = new Date();
let menosCemAnos = new Date(hoje.getYear() -100, hoje.getMonth(), hoje.getDate());
```

Então você terá as seguintes saídas:

```
hoje.toString() // "Wed May 08 2019 18:18:17 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"
menosCemAnos.toString() //"Thu May 08 1919 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"
```

Obviamente, para criar uma data determinada: `new Date(1900,0,1)`

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Mas como aplicar  este caso no datatable editor:?

Comment: Não conheço o componente que você menciona, mas via de regra ele deve ter alguma propriedade onde você seta a data que deseja como ponto de partida, ou propriedades que definem data inicial e final.